# Cleaning up Javascript eventListeners

Tags: javascript, canvas, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a quick question. I want the program to respond when I tap on the screen **OR** when my finger moves on the screen, so I made this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", pointerUpdate);
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", pointerUpdate);
```

But, I feel like there is a better way than making two `eventListener`s. The program also lags a lot because of this. Is there any way to combine these two lines of code into one? Thanks!

Comment: No there ain't an other way, and any other library (jQuery) does the same thing behind the scenes. Also, it is impossible, that the program lags because of adding two event listeners. Verify, that you add them only once, and the function that you are calling.

Comment: And adding to Akxe's comment, what are you doing in `pointerUpdate`??? And an additional note, you don't have to accept an answer if it does not help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method of jQuery to accomplish that ...

```
$('#canvas').on('touchmove touchstart', pointerUpdate);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without libraries?

Comment: umm.. I don't think so :/

Comment: This ain't a solution! It is the same as adding them as you do, but it will also run a lot of checks and internal part of library

Comment: Ya, I know, but its the only possible way to add them at once I guess :)

Comment: @Akxe All I asked was for a way to condense it. Therefore, it solves the problem.

Comment: I agree with Alxe using jQuery adds a ton of unneeded overhead with will only have a negative effect on performance. `["move","start"].forEach(n=>canvas.addEventListener("touch"+n,pointerUpdate));` if you wanted code brevity. -1 for a non answer.